# When and where I can find the UDS-O group photos?

Tags: uds

I think the question title is enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Flickr there is a UDS group where various attendees have left their photos: http://www.flickr.com/groups/uds/

Comment: Thanks, and any info about when?

Comment: Actually today is the last day

`Started: Mon, 09 May 2011 09:00:00 CEST`
`Ends: Fri, 13 May 2011 18:00:00 CEST`

Comment: Cool, i hope it will be release in the newxt hours

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [Official UDS-O group photo set](http://www.pixoulphotography.com/2011/05/18/official-uds-o-group-photo-and-personal-photo-set/).

Below is just one of those images:

[image]

*Ubuntu Developer Summit Oneiric Ocelot (UDS-O) at Corinthia Hotel Budapest, Budapest, Hungary, EU - 9th - 13th May 2011 [cc by-sa 2011 Sean Sosik-Hamor]*